# Rainbow box when running program in Panda3D using VS2010

Tags: python, panda3d

i've been having this weird error after starting to try out "masking" (halfway through an activity given by a lecturer). The lecturer recommended that i create a new solution. However, after making 3 solutions which produced the same error.

http://puu.sh/1foxu <- Picture of the error

http://pastebin.com/GPsLTjdm <- Pastebin for code (used pastebin because Panda3D thingy is indent sensitive)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your box model before reparenting it to its bullet node.

```
self.world.attachRigidBody(np.node())
model = loader.loadModel('models/box.egg')
model.setPos(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)                   # <- Add this line
model.reparentTo(np)
```

Adjusting the model position is needed because Bullet shapes assume that the center of the model is its (0,0,0) coordinates, but in most cases the (0,0,0) is actually the bounds of the model.

**EDIT:**

To solve your texture problem try:

```
model.setTexture(tex, 1)
```

...instead of...

```
model.setTexture(tex)
```

A fragment from the manual:

> Normally, you simply pass 1 as the second parameter to setTexture().
>   Without this override, the texture that is assigned directly at the
>   Geom level will have precedence over the state change you make at the
>   model node, and the texture change won't be made.

Comment: hey! Thanks a lot, the box is now aligned. However, there's still a slight problem. The program isn't using the texture that came with the box (it worked once before rainbow boxes started appearing), it's still using the rainbow textures. Any ideas?

Comment: The box texture is set in box.egg file. You can see it if you open box.egg with a text editor. You can leave that file alone and just overwrite the texture from python code. Take a look at the manual: http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Multitexture_Introduction

Comment: `    model = loader.loadModel('models/box.egg')
    tex = loader.loadTexture('models/wood.png')
    model.setTexture(tex);
`

I tried it and it doesn't work, still rainbow boxes.

Comment: Here's the picture of the texture aligned with the bounding box.

http://puu.sh/1hqOt

Comment: I just loaded the smiley model in and it doesn't revert to the rainbow textures, does this mean there's something wrong with the textures?